# Android Support Library Build v26.X.X Build Error: Attribute "font" already defined

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to upgrade from version `25.3.1` to version `26.X.X` of the support library, but every time I build the project using the newer version I get this error:

```
Error:(357) Attribute "font" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(343) Original attribute defined here.

Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing 
process /Users/johnsmith/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/26.0.1/aapt 
with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I ...
```

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding. I have also tried invalidating caches and restarting Android Studio.

The app builds fine with version `25.3.1` of the support library. I'm using Android Studio 3.0 Beta 2 with version `3.0.0-beta2` of the Android Gradle plugin.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since this error is:

- Android O specific,
- related to a `font` attribute, and
- an error thrown by `aapt`,

my guess is that you have defined a custom attribute named `font` in your application code that conflicts in some manner with the [`android`-namespaced `font` attribute introduced in Android O](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/working-with-fonts.html). Try renaming or removing that custom attribute.

Answer (score 13):

you should change the "font" attribute name that used in customView

```
<declare-styleable name="AATextView">
    <attr name="font" format="string"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

for example :

```
<declare-styleable name="AATextView">
    <attr name="typeface" format="string"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when i updated supporting library to latest version.

After that i have updated all the supporting library to latest version like play services library and firebase library also other third party libraries into latest version.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting the same issue and fixed in following way.

This is issue comes when you upgrade your project to support Android 'O'. 
You can fix the issue with below step. 
1. Check all the support library must have some version.
2. check res folder of all "External Dependency". you will find the culprit dependency resource file which actually creates the issue.[check this image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gki8H.png)