# Android values.xml error while building

Tags: android, gradle

I have a project that has been working absolutely fine. I changed the buildToolsVersion to '26.0.0' and now when I try to clean/rebuild the project I get the following errors within the "values.xml".

Error:(343) Attribute "font" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(319) Original attribute defined here.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Original attribute value:

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomFontTextView"><attr format="string" name="font"/></declare-styleable>
```

Attribute "font" already defined with incompatible format:

```
</attr><attr format="reference" name="font"/><attr format="integer" name="fontWeight"/></declare-styleable>
```

Also "R" cannot be resolved error in my Main Activity.

Any ideas what could be wrong at all?

Thank you.

Comment: Please post your values.xml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Support Library Build v26.X.X Build Error: Attribute "font" already defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45646103/android-support-library-build-v26-x-x-build-error-attribute-font-already-defi)

Comment: Added the values

Comment: I followed the instructions on adding a "font" folder into the "res" directory of the project. It doesn't work, gives the error that font needs to be an xml file. Some research showed that this feature will be fully available from Android Studio versionn 2.4. what can I do to avoid the above errors for the moment? What buildToolsVersion should I revert back to?

Comment: Any ideas at all?

Answer (score 1):

change the "font" attribute name that used in CustomFontTextView

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomFontTextView">
<attr format="string" name="font"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

to

```
<declare-styleable name="AATextView">
    <attr format="string" name="typeface" />
</declare-styleable>
```